# Invalid layer when dragging tif archive in QGIS

Tags: qgis, layers, error

I'm new in **QGIS**. I followed this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6adjrQ_VtHQ&t=445s in order to make a bathymetric map, and when I drag the .tif appears this red window

**Invalid layer: GDAL provider**

> Cannot open GDAL dataset C:/Users/casa/Desktop/Lab/coquimbo.tif:
>   `C:/Users/casa/Desktop/Lab/coquimbo.tif' not recognized as a supported
>   file format. Raster layer El proveedor no es válido (proveedor: gdal,
>   URL: C:/Users/casa/Desktop/Lab/coquimbo.tif)

I am using **QGIS 2.18.15**

Comment: can you download again the raster?Maybe it's corrupt

Comment: use `gdalinfo` to check if the tif is valid